# Changing commerce_line item quantity to 3 decimal places

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to change the precision of Drupal commerce quantities to 3 decimal places.

To do this I edited *drupal_commerce_line_item* and changed the *quantity* field from `decimal(10,2)` to `decimal(11,3)`.

Is this OK? (don't want repercussions) and is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, changing the `commerce_line_item` field's SQL (schema) definition ought to be enough. However, a cursory review of a few modules shows that some of them will round the value to 2 decimal places before using it, negating the change. You'll probably need to change it and then test it to ensure that every module you're using it with will work as you intend.